# When should I be opening and closing websocket connections for a chat inside of another app?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, graphql, serverless

I'm using Serverless, AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda to attempt to send real-time messages and there's a few examples I've found that nail this concept. I'm having issues wrapping my head around where WebSocket connections should be opening in my app.

I have created a GraphQL API and a multi-page and I would like to have a real-time chat app embedded into it across all pages, similar to your Facebook or WhatsApp or whatever. I have implemented GraphQL mutations and queries to make Threads where Users and Messages would reside in and those have their own mutations and queries as well and I also have 4 Lambda functions set up. One for the GraphQL server, and for WebSockets I have open, close and sendMessage.

I thought about opening a WebSocket connection whenever the GraphQL server gets executed but then I feel like this would keep the Lambda up until the connection closes which I think is against the Serverless framework philosophy and best practices in the sense that the Lambda function would have to wait for the WebSocket connection to close for the Lambda to finish its execution. But at the same time, I feel like for a real-time chat app to work on another app across all pages, it should stay up? Are there any other options in the back-end where I could possibly be opening the connection?

The other alternative is to connect it on the front-end side of things?

Comment: You would need to use **AWS IoT** for that purpose.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why I need AWS IoT? It was one of the options I've seen for WebSockets, but it isn't available the the Canadian region which is where I'm trying to keep things in. Also, it's not like the API Gateway + Lambda didn't work, it's more of a 'not know where to open the connection' if IoT solves this problem, I'd like to know how